# Returning an array from solidity contract to react front-end, gives only first and last element of the array

Tags: reactjs, solidity

I tried to call a function in react from solidity contract and logged the result (returning array or mapping in solidity) in console.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Select extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.props.data;
    }

    getSuppliers = async (event) => {
        const { accounts, contract, productId } = this.state;
        await contract.methods.getSuppliersOfProduct(productId).call({ from: accounts[0] }, (err,result) => {
            if(err){
                console.log("Error at product: ", err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Result: ", result);
            }
        });
    }

    changeHandler = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="App">
                <input 
                    name="productId" 
                    value={this.state.productId}  
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    placeholder="Product ID"
                />
                <button onClick={this.getSuppliers}>Get Suppliers</button>
                <br />
                <h1>{this.state.productId}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Select;
```

I expected to return the "result" from "getSuppliers()" function as an array of 4 addresses, but it only returns the array of 2, that is, the first and last element of the returning array.

Comment: I don't see the contract code, so I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.

I was just return a mapping from contract to react, like this,

   mapping (uint => address[]) productsupplychain;
   
 function getSuppliersOfProduct(uint productid) public returns(address[] memory) {
        return productsupplychain[productid];
     }

In Remix, it returns an address[] of 4 elements, but in react, when I logged the result into console, it only shows first and last elements.